# Java Pcap loop not starting

Tags: java, pcap, jnetpcap

I using jnetpcap library for listening to network traffic, and basically using the PcapPacketHandlers for listening to packets, after initializing them I start a pcap.loop() method so it will start listening.
However about 50% of the time when I run my program the loops will not start and the program just gets stuck, no errors, no exceptions nothing. I only get 1 prinout and nothing more, this printout: loop1DEVICES CHOSEN: \Device\NPF_{0A6670EB-FED6-4AD0-9EE6-1F9BA35A75A5},\Device\NPF_{E0FB8017-9FFB-4489-A894-8D256394087C}
IP: [removed]
THS SHOULD BE IT : 192.168.1.2
IP: [removed]
THS SHOULD BE IT : 147.66.12.4
start ...
Real start
Loop1 should start now :
Loop2 should start now :

This is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jnetpcap.Pcap;
import org.jnetpcap.PcapBpfProgram;
import org.jnetpcap.PcapDumper;
import org.jnetpcap.PcapIf;
import org.jnetpcap.nio.JBuffer;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket;
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacketHandler;
import org.jnetpcap.protocol.network.Ip4;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.desktop.AppEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Switch extends Application
{
    private int pcn1=0;
    private int pcn2=0;
    private int counter =0;
    private Map<String, ScheduledExecutorService> pingThreads;
    public static ArrayList<String> devices;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    PcapPacketHashTable packetTable = PcapPacketHashTable.getInstance();





    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //GUI SETUP
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Network Traffic");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 835, 1000));
        primaryStage.show();


        //Switch setup
        SwitchMacTable macT= SwitchMacTable.getInstance();
        Port p1= new Port(null,null,"Fa0/",null,null,macT);
        Port p2= new Port(null,null,"Fa0/",null,null,macT);
        Packet statisticsInPort1 = new Packet();
        Packet statisticsOutPort1 = new Packet();
        Packet statisticsInPort2 = new Packet();
        Packet statisticsOutPort2 = new Packet();
        p1.setIn(statisticsInPort1);
        p1.setOut(statisticsOutPort2);
        p2.setIn(statisticsInPort2);
        p2.setOut(statisticsOutPort1);
        // packet sniffer
        int snaplen = 64 * 1024;
        int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS;
        int timeout = 1000;           // 10ms
        int opt = 0;
        int mask = 0xffffff00;


        //start GUI
        GUI gui= loader.getController();
        gui.initialize(p1,p2);

        devices = new ArrayList<String>();



        List devicelist = new ArrayList();
        List<PcapIf> tempdevices = new ArrayList<PcapIf>();

        StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();
        String err = "";

        //nacitanie sietovych zariadeni
        int foundd = Pcap.findAllDevs(devicelist, errbuf);

        if (foundd != Pcap.OK) {
            System.err.printf("Can't read list of devices, error is %s", errbuf.toString());

            return;
        }

        for (Object dev : devicelist) {
            tempdevices.add((PcapIf) dev);
            devices.add(dev.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(tempdevices.size() + " network devices found:");


        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<String> dvar = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PcapIf device : tempdevices) {
            String description = (device.getDescription() != null) ? device.getDescription() : "No description available";

            dvar.add(description);



        }

        gui.addCombos(dvar);

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                int iiii = 1;
                   int b=5;
                   int yt=iiii+b;
               System.out.print("smp");
                    try {



                        while(p1.getStop()==0) {
                           System.out.print("loop2");

                            while (p1.getStart() == 0) {
                                //waiting for adapter choice.
                                int ii = 1;int bbb=5;
                                int yttt=iiii+bbb;
                              System.out.print("loop1");
                            }

                            PcapIf device = tempdevices.get(gui.getAdapterC1());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);

                            PcapIf device2 = tempdevices.get(gui.getAdapterC2());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            byte[] ar = device.getHardwareAddress();
                            byte[] ar2 = device2.getHardwareAddress();
                            Packet np = new Packet();
                            String devname1 = device.getName();
                            String devname2 = device2.getName();
                            System.out.println("DEVICES CHOSEN: " + devname1 + "," + devname2);
                            InetAddress adaIp1=null;
                            InetAddress adaIp2=null;

                            if (ar != null) {

                                System.out.println("IP: "+device.getAddresses().get(0).getAddr());
                                byte[] adapip = device.getAddresses().get(0).getAddr().getData();
                                try {
                                    adaIp1 = InetAddress.getByAddress(adapip);
                                    System.out.println("THS SHOULD BE IT : "+ adaIp1.getHostAddress());

                                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }


                            }
                            if (ar2 != null) {

                                System.out.println("IP: "+device2.getAddresses().get(0).getAddr());
                                byte[] adapip = device2.getAddresses().get(0).getAddr().getData();
                                try {
                                    adaIp2 = InetAddress.getByAddress(adapip);
                                    System.out.println("THS SHOULD BE IT : "+ adaIp2.getHostAddress());

                                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }

                            }


                            //Open the selected device to capture packets
                            Pcap pcap = Pcap.openLive(device.getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            Pcap pcap2 = Pcap.openLive(device2.getName(), snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            if (pcap == null || pcap2 == null) {
                                if (pcap == null) {
                                    System.err.printf("Error  while opening device for capture: " + errbuf.toString());
                                } else {
                                    System.err.printf("Error while opening device for capture: " + errbuf.toString());
                                }
                                return;
                            }

                            PcapBpfProgram program = new PcapBpfProgram();
                            String filter = "ether proto \\ip or arp or udp or tcp or icmp or (tcp port 80) or (tcp port 443)";

                            if (pcap.compile(program, filter, opt, mask) != Pcap.OK) {
                                System.out.println(pcap.getErr());
                                return;
                            }

                            if (pcap.setFilter(program) != Pcap.OK) {
                                System.out.println(pcap.getErr());
                                return;
                            }
                            if (pcap2.compile(program, filter, opt, mask) != Pcap.OK) {
                                System.out.println(pcap2.getErr());
                                return;
                            }

                            if (pcap2.setFilter(program) != Pcap.OK) {
                                System.out.println(pcap2.getErr());
                                return;
                            }

                            System.out.println("start ...");

                            p1.setInterfaceName(devname1);
                            p2.setInterfaceName(devname2);
                            p1.setPcap(pcap);
                            p2.setPcap(pcap2);
                            PingThread pt1 = new PingThread(null,adaIp1,macT,null);
                            PingThread pt2 = new PingThread(null,adaIp2,macT,null);
                            byte[] adapterMacAddress = device.getHardwareAddress();
                            byte[] adapter2MacAddress = device2.getHardwareAddress();
                            System.out.println("Real start");

                            // LOOP    1 1 1 1 1  LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP

                            PcapPacketHandler<String> port1 = (packet, user) -> {
                                System.out.println("PICSA");
                                if (1 == 1) {

                                    if((Arrays.equals(packet.getByteArray(6, 6), adapterMacAddress)) || (Arrays.equals(packet.getByteArray(6, 6), adapter2MacAddress)))
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("ret1 + " + p1.getIn().bytesToHexString(packet.getByteArray(0, 6)));
                                        return ;
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("p total size: "+ packet.getTotalSize() + " size: "+ packet.size());
                                    if (packetTable.contains(packet)) {
                                        System.out.println("REMOVING PACKET");
                                        packetTable.remove(packet);
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    ArrayList<String> ars = p1.getIn().categorize(packet);
                                    String destIP = ars.get(0);
                                    String srcIP = ars.get(1);
                                    String maca = ars.get(2);

                                    //ICMP PING NOT YET IGNORED, DO IT NEXT TIME !!!!
                                    macT.addToMacTable(packet, 1, p1);  //addmac,refrespack1,setbytepack,sendpcap,categ2,refresh2


                                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                        gui.refresh(macT.getMacAddress());
                                    });


                                    packetTable.put(packet);
                                    pcap2.sendPacket(packet);


                                    p1.getOut().categorize(packet);

                                    System.out.println("pack sent");
                                    Platform.runLater(() -> {

                                        gui.refreshPacketCounters(p1.getIn().getChange(), 0);
                                        gui.refreshPacketCounters(p1.getOut().getChange(), 2);

                                    });

                                   // PingThread.startPingThread(srcIP, pt1.getSourceAddresss(), pt1.getSmts(), maca);


                                }
                                }
                                ;




                            // LOOP    2 2 222  LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP



                            PcapPacketHandler<String> port2 = (packet, user) -> {
                                System.out.println("picsa2");
                                if (1 == 1) {
                                    if((Arrays.equals(packet.getByteArray(6, 6), adapterMacAddress)) || (Arrays.equals(packet.getByteArray(6, 6), adapter2MacAddress)))
                                { System.out.println("ret2 + " + p1.getIn().bytesToHexString(packet.getByteArray(0, 6))) ;
                                    return ;
                                }
                                if (   packetTable.contains(packet)) {
                                    System.out.println("REMOVING PACKET");
                                    packetTable.remove(packet);
                                    return ;
                                }
                                    System.out.println("GOTR PACK ///////////////////////////////////////");
                                ArrayList<String> ars = p2.getIn().categorize(packet);
                                String  destIP = ars.get(0);
                                String srcIP = ars.get(1);
                                String maca= ars.get(2);

                                    macT.addToMacTable(packet, 2, p2);
                                    System.out.println(p1.getIn().bytesToHexString(adapter2MacAddress) + "  or "+ adapter2MacAddress);


                                 //   Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                   //     gui.refresh(macT.getMacAddress());
                                    //});


                                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                    gui.refresh(macT.getMacAddress());
                                });



                                int packetH = packet.hashCode();
                                packetTable.put( packet);
                                    pcap.sendPacket(packet);


                                            p2.getOut().categorize(packet);

                                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                            gui.refreshPacketCounters(p2.getIn().getChange(), 1);
                                            gui.refreshPacketCounters(p2.getOut().getChange(), 3);
                                        });

                                //PingThread.startPingThread(srcIP, pt2.getSourceAddresss(),pt2.getSmts());

                                }
                            }
                                ;

                            System.out.println("Loop1 should start now :");
                                new Thread(() -> {
                                    pcap.loop(Pcap.LOOP_INFINITE, port1, "pcap1");
                                }).start();
                            System.out.println("Loop2 should start now :");
                                pcap2.loop(Pcap.LOOP_INFINITE, port2,"pcap2");



                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("WTF?");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I tried everything but I'm running out of ideas how to even understand the cause of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions. Try checking for error codes returned from your two pcap.loop() calls:

```
System.out.println("Loop1 should start now :");
    new Thread(() -> {
        int result = pcap.loop(Pcap.LOOP_INFINITE, port1, "pcap1");
        if (result < 0) 
            System.out.println(pcap.getErr());
            
    }).start();
System.out.println("Loop2 should start now :");
    int result = pcap2.loop(Pcap.LOOP_INFINITE, port2,"pcap2");
    if (result < 0) 
        System.out.println(pcap.getErr());
```

Second, if possible, please migrate to [jNetpcap v2](https://github.com/slytechs-repos/jnetpcap). It has full support going forward and works well currently. It requires a minimum of JDK19 however because of its use of Foreign Function feature which is still in preview in JDK19/20.